# How to install new bower packages using yarn which is only available in bower

Tags: bower, yarnpkg

How to install new bower packages using yarn, i am already using yarn but don't know how to add package which is only available in bower. i want to install bower package "angular-utf8-base64" but i have currently Yarn package manager, Don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/) for how to migrate from bower to yarn, might be a good place to start looking for how you might accomplish this.  Specifically note, that when a project is migrated from bower to yarn it creates yarn dependencies like

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@bower_components/angular-utf8-base64" : "stranger82/angular-utf8-base64#~0.0.5" 
    }
}
```

Edit: It looks like the package stranger82/angular-utf8-base64 [does exist](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/angular-utf8-base64) as an npm/yarn package